# Is there a way to use expressions in data tables - I am using cucumber protractor framework

Tags: protractor, cucumber

I have a requirement where my data table value in feature file will be replaced with dynamic data before submitting it to step definition.

e.g. current table has "User1" as hardcoded value

Background:

```
Given There are following users
  | Name          | Password   | Roles       | Full Name  |
  | User1         | Welcome01_ | Everything  | Test User1 |
```

I need to achieve something like this below, the {prefix} has to to be replaced with different values like "S01" "S02" .. which will result in different users like "S01User1" "S02User1"

Background:

```
Given There are following users
  | Name                  | Password   | Roles       | Full Name  |
  | {prefix}User1         | Welcome01_ | Everything  | Test User1 |
```

Approaches tried: with cucumber-expressions by using a transformer to create custom parameter type.

Limitation noticed: I can use the {prefix} only in statements like in Given, When etc.. but not inside table value.

Any suggestions or pointers to achieve this?

Automation stack : Protractor  + Typescript + cucumber-protractor framework

Adding Note: {prefix} is dynamically sent during test execution from protractor command line parameters

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `Scenario Outline` with an `Examples` datatable.

See https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#scenario-outline

Comment: hello, the problem in using Scenario Outline would be that they are not known during feature file creation ,the value for {prefix} will be sent from protractor command line parameter using config file during execution ..

Comment: Keep in mind that BDD should be high level. Maybe you rather want to write one step which reads the config file and iterate over it instead? Like `Given the users defined in the config`> although it makes the actual values invisible for a reader of the scenario

Comment: Agree, it is a little off from norm. We did have this kind of dependency injection in cucumber-jvm with Junit test framework using spring framework but not able to find the right dependency injection method with protractor + cucumber. 
We will be using the user again in later statements to login etc. it has to be replaced in all places in some way ...